# How to draw graphs using Quartz Framework

Tags: iphone, ios, graph, quartz-graphics, uiviewanimation

I want to draw graph (ECG Type) for heart rate monitors application in iPhone. I dont want to use core plot, but like to develop with quartz. I am receiving heart beat values from bluetooth device, now i want to create the graph based upon the values received from BLE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first simple approach would be to use `UIBezierPath` to draw a line in `drawRect:` of your view. You would have to convert the values you receive into the coordinate system of your view and then create an instance of `UIBezierPath` where you add all relevant point with `addLineToPoint:`. In the end you call `[bezierPath stroke]` to actually draw the line. You could create a Datasource-Protocol for your ViewController and a `reload` method on your view which triggers the views to redraw whenever new data is received.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me, but my issue is, i am getting values from a BLE device (75,83,92 etc), I have to plot them in my view as a graph moving towards x axis, so my y will be the value coming from the device and for the x, i will add some constant values, but the thing is when the graph reaches to the end position of the screen (320), what will happen then?The previous points needs to be removed from the screen, how? Also how should i update my graph every second with the new value, so it will not generate the whole graph from starting?

Comment: You need to determine which points are actually visible and then feed them to the view. Start with a redraw on every tick. If that doesn't perform well enough start optimising it.

Comment: How do I clear the drawing and redraw from scratch? my line just keeps getting longer and longer like the snake :)

Answer (score -2):

Downlaod the sample code from bellow url :)

[Sample code here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/508075/SampleHeartRateApp.zip)

Don't forget +1

Thanks,

:)